# Wrong message , File uploaded but still "Maximum request length exceeded"

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, ajax, jquery-file-upload

I have wrote an upload file method in javascript to upload big files it slpits thefiles in blobs and reattach the blobs in server side again so I can upload big files but there is a problem... after the upload is done and I receive the file in server side (the fileuploads completely), it gives me this `Maximum request length exceeded`

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head id="Head1" runat="server">
    <title>uploading file using jquery with generic handler ashx</title>
    <link id="Link2" rel="stylesheet" runat="server" media="screen" href="~/fileupload.css" />
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://malsup.github.com/jquery.form.js"></script>
    <%--<script src="JavaScript1.js" type="text/javascript"></script>--%>
    <script src="MyScript.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</head>
<body>

    <form id="form1" runat="server" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        <div id="uploadFile">
            <div class="fileuploadDiv">
                <div class="status"></div>
                <input type="file" name="files[]" multiple="multiple" id="files" class="fileSelect" />
                <input type="submit" value="Upload" class="button" id="btnUpload" />
                <%--<div id="progressbar" class="progress"></div>--%>
                <div class="progress" id="progressbar">
                    <div class="bar" id="bar"></div>
                    <div class="percent" id="percent">0%</div>
                </div>
                <div id="messages"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </form>
</body>
```

MyScript.js

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#btnUpload").click(function (evt) {
        var blobs = [];
        var fl = document.getElementById("files");
        var L = fl.files.length;
        var elem = document.getElementById("bar");
        var per = document.getElementById("percent");

        for (var i = 0; i < L ; i++) {
            var file = fl.files[i];
            var bytes_per_chunk = 3*1024*1024; //1048576
            var start = 0;
            var end = bytes_per_chunk;
            var size = file.size;
            var j = 1;
            while (start < size) {
                //push the fragments to an array
                blobs.push(file.slice(start, end));
                start = end;
                end = start + bytes_per_chunk;
            }
            while (blob = blobs.shift()) {
                var fileName = file.name;
                var fileType = file.type;
                var fileSize = file.size / 100;
                var rec = 0;
                rec = blob + rec;
                var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();

                xhr.open('POST', 'Handler.ashx', false);

                xhr.onload = function () {
                    alert("in for");
                    elem.style.width = j + "%";
                    per.innerHTML = j + "%";
                    j++;
                    rec = 0;

                }

                xhr.setRequestHeader('X_FILE_NAME', fileName);
                xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', fileType);
                xhr.send(blob);
            }
        }
    });
});
```

Handler.ashx

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.IO;

namespace test
{
    public class Handler : IHttpHandler
    {
        int fileCount = 0;
        public static void AppendAllBytes(string path, byte[] bytes)
        {
            //argument-checking here.
            try
            {
                using (var stream = new FileStream(path, FileMode.Append))
                {
                    stream.Write(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
                }
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                throw;
            }
        }

        public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
        {
            try
            {
                byte[] buffer = new byte[context.Request.ContentLength];
                context.Request.InputStream.Read(buffer, 0, context.Request.ContentLength);
                string fileName = context.Request.Headers.Get(11);
                AppendAllBytes(context.Server.MapPath("~/upload/" + fileName), buffer);  
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                throw;
            }              
        }

        public bool IsReusable
        {
            get
            {
                return false;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: check your web.config for maximum request length, and increase it

Comment: but the problem is that,I don't have access to server config file and this is a test I am doing on my computer, for this reason I have used the slicing methos. and in fact it is uploading the file successfully but gives this error also

Comment: when you say "it gives me Maximum request length exceeded", what is "it" and where does this "message" manifest itself?

Comment: I mean that the file is uploaded successfully but after uploading the file, it gives this error also. in fact it should not gives the rror because the code is working fine with uploading

Comment: in what way does "it" give this error - I guess I don't understand where you're seeing the error

Comment: a new page loads with the error : 
Maximum request length exceeded.

Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code. 

Exception Details: System.Web.HttpException: Maximum request length exceeded.

Source Error: 

An unhandled exception was generated during the execution of the current web request. Information regarding the origin and location of the exception can be identified using the exception stack trace below.

Comment: Stack trace :

[HttpException (0x80004005): Maximum request length exceeded.]
   System.Web.HttpRequest.GetEntireRawContent() +9686039
   System.Web.HttpRequest.GetMultipartContent() +63
   System.Web.HttpRequest.FillInFormCollection() +165
   System.Web.HttpRequest.EnsureForm() +75
   System.Web.HttpRequest.get_Form() +12
   System.Web.HttpRequest.get_HasForm() +9687455
   System.Web.UI.Page.GetCollectionBasedOnMethod(Boolean

Comment: dontReturnNull) +95
   System.Web.UI.Page.DeterminePostBackMode() +69
   System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint) +130

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I Solved it Finally

the problem is the "Submit" that I changed it to button so itdoes not send the whole file also after submitting the button

I did this :

```
input type="button" value="Upload" class="button" id="btnUpload" />
```

instead of

```
input type="submit" value="Upload" class="button" id="btnUpload" />
```